# Twitter Feed in my Android app

Tags: android, rss, twitter, feed

I want to insert a Twitter feed in my Android app.
I just don't know where to begin, I have tried to Google it but I did not succeed.

I would like it to look almost look the same as the one in my mobile website, this one is made with jQuery:

http://m.psvhandbal.nl/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to grab feed from user, the simplest way is to use Twitter Api and parse xml response with e.g SAXParser(built-in Android). After that you can populate database with this feed, and show tweets to user in ListView.

http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html

https://dev.twitter.com/docs

Comment: Thanks guys, i used http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/05/android-programming-tutorial-a-simple-twitter-feed-reader/

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already made the feed look how you want in jQuery you also have the option to show what you've already created inside of a WebView in your application.

Comment: True, I already got the webview based app. But I want to add more features, so I am rebuilding it. Trying to train myself in programming